How do I find the volume of this body?
I need help with finding the volume of the body given by
$B = \{(x,y,z) \in D \colon 0\leq xyz \leq t^3\}$
Where $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is given by $0 \leq x \leq t, 0 \leq y \leq t, 0 \leq z \leq t$. The number t is also greater than zero. So $D$ is a cube of side length $t$.
I was under the impression that the volume of $B$ was the same as the volume of $D$, $t^3$, but my teacher said that wasn't the case and now I don't really know what to do.
I tried to compute it with double integrals, but I am having a tough time with the bounds.

Suppose $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in D$. That's if and only if $ 0\le x_i \le t$. Then, $0 \le x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \le t^3.$ Therefore $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in B$.
But, by definition of $B$, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in B$, then $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in D$.
Therefore the volume of $B$ is exactly the volume of $D$.
Likely your teacher forgot that the set $B$ is defined as a restriction of the cube $D$. Your teacher may have thought you were talking about $B' := \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^{\ge 0} : 0 \le xyz \le t^3 \}$ instead of how you defined $B$, which has infinite volume..
